# Incorrect number of bindings supplied Sqlite query in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas

When running the following code in python I am given the error: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied. For the query statement.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('viber_messages2')

cur = conn.cursor()
cur = cur.execute("""SELECT DISTINCT messages.conversation_id
                FROM messages
                INNER JOIN participants  ON messages.participant_id = participants._id
                WHERE messages.conversation_id IS NOT NULL;""")

query = ("""SELECT messages._id, messages.body, messages.conversation_id, messages.participant_id, participants_info.number, participants_info.contact_name
        FROM messages
        INNER JOIN
        participants ON messages.participant_id = participants._id
        INNER JOIN
        participants_info ON participants.participant_info_id = participants_info._id;""")

with open('messages.html', 'w') as h, open('test.txt', 'w') as t:
for convo in cur.fetchall():
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn, params=convo)

    # HTML WRITE
    h.write(df.to_html())
    h.write('<br/>')

    # TXT WRITE
    t.write(df.to_string())
    t.write('\n\n')

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a close look at your query

```
SELECT messages._id, messages.body, messages.conversation_id, messages.participant_id, participants_info.number, participants_info.contact_name
        FROM messages
        INNER JOIN
        participants ON messages.participant_id = participants._id
        INNER JOIN
        participants_info ON participants.participant_info_id = participants_info._id
```

There are no place holder here to which parameters can be bound. But how are you executing this query?

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn, params=convo)
```

You should instead do

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
```

Comment: Ah yes my mistake! It has fixed the error, however my code is no longer splitting the results into seperate tables based on the conversation_id within the messages table now however.

Comment: Scratch that I've fixed it! Thank you!